# Why is Naga shown with 3, 5, 7, 9 heads?

Tags: belief, history, other-religions, art

Why in art and some religions, Naga is shown with different number of heads?

What is the significance of the [Cambodian Naga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C4%81ga#/media/File:NagaPhnomPenh.jpg)?